# Anyone know of any Meteor template sliders?

Tags: meteor, slider, uislider, flexslider, meteor-packages

I have infographics charts on two seperate templates/pages, and have been looking in vain for a package that would enable the two templates to become slider contents in a single page. 
Do any packages with theses requirement exist, perhaps you could recommend a slider package or even have a better solution?

Find below an example of one of my infographic template/page:

```
<template name="myDoughnutChart">
    Total number of users Doughnut chart: <br>
    {{notLoggedIn}} logged in <br>
    {{activelyUsingApp}} are currently using Pescrow <br>
    {{idleUsers}} are logged in but idle <br>
    {{totalNumbersOfUsers}} are the total number of users!

    <canvas id="myDoughnutChart" class="img-responsive" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</template>
```

Here is yet another example of my infographic template/page:

```
<template name="radarChart">
    Top three most visited pages:  <br>
    <canvas id="radarChart" class="img-responsive" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</template>
```

Find below the **onlinePresence** Page/Template were I would like to implement the slider between templates: **myDoughnutChart** and **radarChart**

```
<template name="onlinePresence">

    <div class="container">
       <div class="pageTitle" align="center" > Online Presence </div>

       {{>myDoughnutChart id='myDoughnutChart' width="300" height="400"}}
       {{>radarChart id='radarChart' width="300" height="400"}}    
    </div>

</template>
```

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: "Slider" normally refers to a control - like volume, color intensity. What are you trying to do? Some kind of motion that switches between two pieces of content? A carousel? Have you looked at what's available through bootstrap?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Yes, I am trying to switch between two pieces of content, each in their own templates e.g. `<template name="radarChart">` and `<template name="myDoughnutChart">`. I have then attached both of them into one main template `<template name="onlinePresence">` using: {{>radarChart}} & {{>myDoughnutChart}}

Comment: @MichelFloyd I check out the Bootstrap Components Carousel, which seems like THE most fitting solution, however I can't figure out how to switch between the two contents `{{>radarChart}}` &  `{{>myDoughnutChart}}`  within the `<template name="onlinePresence">` template. Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to need to put each piece of content in it's own div and let bootstrap control which one is visible and how to transition between them.